# Stop/Cancel JUnit 5 test execution (started programmatically)

Tags: junit, junit5

I have some JUnit 5 tests, running and started within an OSGi container.
The code to start the test execution looks somewhat like this:

```
LauncherConfig launcherConfig = LauncherConfig.builder().addTestEngines( new JupiterTestEngine() ).build();
Launcher launcher = LauncherFactory.create( launcherConfig );

LauncherDiscoveryRequest request = LauncherDiscoveryRequestBuilder.request()
     .selectors( selectClass( testName ) )
     .build();
TestPlan testPlan = launcher.discover( request );

launcher.execute( request );
```

As some of these tests require manual steps with physical hardware, the tests don't run in a CI environment and are meant to be executed manually by a tester. Therefore, tests may run pretty long (especially if tester did not perform the required manual steps).

**Question**: How can I stop a running test execution?

*Background*: I would like to make sure that only one test is running at a time, to avoid interference between the tests. On the other hand, I don't want that one "unfinished" test is blocking test execution forever.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this is not supported in todays JUnit5 implementation :(

https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/1880

It was scheduled for version 5.8 but didn't make it into the release.
If you have the same issue, take a look at the Github issue, maybe it's solved in between.